# Kendo UI Scheduler destroy recurring event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm using Kendo UI Scheduler.
I have a recurring event with couple exceptions.
When I try to delete entire series of recurring event then in parameterMap function options.model contains only recurring event without exceptions.
And after deletion these exceptions still exist on the scheduler, so i need re-read datasource.

I checked on the [kendo ui demo scheduler](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index), in their example the options.model contains recurring event and all exceptions of this event and removes from scheduler the recurring event and all exceptions.

Exception has the recurrenceId to recurring event.
I would like to get in options.model exceptions as well.

here is my code:

```
 function InitScheduler() {
            $("#Scheduler").kendoScheduler({
                name: "Scheduler",
                date: GetSelectDate(),
                timezone: GetTimeZone(),
                views: [
                    { type: "day", selected: isActiveView("day") },
                    { type: "workWeek", selected: isActiveView("workWeek") },
                    { type: "week", selected: isActiveView("week") },
                    { type: "month", selected: isActiveView("month") }
                ],
                dataSource: {
                    batch: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "~/Calendar/SchedulerReader",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },
                        create: {
                            url: "~/Calendar/SchedulerEditor",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },
                        update: {
                            url: "~/Calendar/SchedulerEditor",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },
                        destroy: {
                            url: "~/Calendar/SchedulerRemover",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },       
                        parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                            //here when operation == 'destroy' options.models contains only one event without exception
                            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    schema: {
                        data: function (response) {
                            return response.Data;
                        },
                        model: {
                            id: "id",
                            fields: {
                                id: {from: "ApptID" },
                                entryID: { from: "EntryID", type: "string" },
                                start: { from: "Start", type: "date" },
                                end: { from: "End", type: "date" },
                                startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                                endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                                title: { from: "Subject" },
                                titleEvent: { from: "TitleEvent" },
                                location: { from: "Location" },
                                description: { from: "Description" },
                                recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                                recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                                recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                                ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 1 },
                                isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" },
                                useTz: { type: "boolean", from: "UseTimezones" },
                                history: { from: "History" },
                                categories: { from: "Categories", nullable: true }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.
Just changed model to:

model: {
    id: "apptID",
    fields: {
        apptID: { from: "ApptID", type: "string" },
        entryID: { from: "EntryID", type: "string" },
        start: { from: "Start", type: "date" },
        end: { from: "End", type: "date" },
        startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
        endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
        title: { from: "Subject" },
        titleEvent: { from: "TitleEvent" },
        location: { from: "Location" },
        description: { from: "Description" },
        recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID", type: "string" },
        recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
        recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
        ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 1 },
        isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" },
        useTz: { type: "boolean", from: "UseTimezones" },
        history: { from: "History" },
        categories: { from: "Categories", nullable: true }
    }
}

Comment: OP changed the `model` `id` value, the `fields` `id`/`apptID`, and the `recurrenceId` value.